# Edit and update excel from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that download a specific xlsx file from SharePoint online to a local folder.
I am searching for colors and values in the sheet in a specific column. There are 2 objects. One for values and one for colors. I need to edit the sheet: replace the colors with string and remove the color background and the same for the second.
Next I need to save it and upload to SharePoint online.
Anyone can help me with that?
Here the object that holds the colors and values.

```
$excel2 = "C:\Temp\SharedFolder\test.xlsx"
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $false
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False # Disable comfirmation prompts
    $workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excel2)
    $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("VIP List")

    $patches = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
        $val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, [uint16]$answer).Interior.ColorIndex # 2 is column B
        if ($val -eq $searchcolorForPatch)  {
            # output an object with both values from columns A and B
            [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2}
        }
    }
    $cabs = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
        $val2 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, [uint16]$answer).value2 # 2 is column B
        if ($val2 -match $searchValue)  {
            # output an object with both values from columns A and B
            [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2}
        }
    }
```

I tried to add this and change to color 3

```
 $patches = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
        $val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex # 2 is column B
        if ($val -eq 14)  {
            # output an object with both values from columns A and B
            [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2
            ($worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex) = '3'
            }
        }
    }
    $workbook.SaveAs($excel2)
    $workbook.Close($false)
    $excel.Quit()
```

I think this can work but I need to change the color and set a string inside
Currently only the color was changed

```
$patches = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    $val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex # 2 is column B
    if ($val -eq 14)  {
        # output an object with both values from columns A and B
        [PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = '3'
        }
    }
}
```

Need to change the color to -4142 and write inside a string
[image]

Case 2:
Need to find all the cells with color 4 (green) and has a string 'add' inside. currently know to collect only by color code
[image]

Comment: The `.ColorIndex` takes an integer value, not a string, so do `$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3`. If you want to **remove** the color, set it to value [xlColorIndexNone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolorindex): `$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142`. To set a new value to a cell, simply do `$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4) = 'New Value Here'`

Comment: Yes it will work but I need in addition to reverting the color to -4142 to write something inside the cell

Comment: You can do both actions on the same cell. First remove the backgroundcolor and then on that same cell set the new value. Perhaps you can provide a small screenshot of what the file looks like and how you want to change that to make it more clear?

Comment: 1. Thank you Theo. I don't know how can I do it...
How to change the color and write in it. 
2. I ask many time in the past how can I search for cells in a specific color and have a specific string inside but no one answer me
3. Need to upload it to SPO after the changes
I will be happy to get all the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is too long for a comment, so here goes:

If you have opened your Excel you can search for the cells with a certain background color, AND change the cells value like this:

```
# as example, we look for Green background, for more colors, see https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/colorindex/
$colorToSearch = 4  
for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    $color = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Interior.ColorIndex # 2 is column B where to look for the background color
    $value = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Value2
    if ($color -eq $colorToSearch -and $value -eq 'add' )  {
        # remove the background color from that cell
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142   # constant: xlColorIndexNone
        # now update the same cell's content
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 2) = 'New Value to add to this cell'
    }
}

# save the file with a new name ?
$workbook.SaveAs($excel2)  # remember to put a complete, absolute path and filename here
$workbook.Close($false)

# or save using the same name, so just save the changes in it
# $workbook.Close($true)

# quit Excel
$excel.Quit()

# and remove the used COM objects from memory, otherwise they keep file locks to the file
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

When it comes to uploading the file to SharePoint, please have a look at the code [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/upload-files-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)

---

From your comments.
If you only want to **find** green cells with the value 'add' in them and then collect the Patch numbers from column 1 in the same row, do this:

```
# as example, we look for Green background, for more colors, see https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/colorindex/
$colorToSearch = 4   # green
$valueToSearch = 'add'
$patches = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    # get the background color and value of the cell in column 4
    $color = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex # # 2 is column where to look for the background color
    $value = $value = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 4).Value2
    if ($color -eq $colorToSearch -and $value -eq $valueToSearch )  {
        # just output the patch number from column 1
        # that means that variable $patches will become an array of strings
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2

        # or if you rather have that, output an object that has both
        # the row number and the Patch number in it
        # [PsCustomObject]@{
            # Row   = $row
            # Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2
        # }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is an option to edit the excel that located in the SPO? Instead of downloading it locally? I have tried it before but encountered with issues
What about my question regarding to the color and string in the same cell?
There is a way to do that? I want to find only the green and has the string inside 'add'

Comment: @NirCarmona Aha, so the cell needs to be green **and** contain the text `add`. Please see my updated answer for that. As for updating the file within SharePoint, that is not possible I'm afraid. You **have to** download it, change it and then send it back to SharePoint, overwriting the original.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I want to collect to an object called $patches as you can see in the first code I wrote all the green cells that has the string 'add'. Currently I am searching to green and put in $patches and searching for a string without color and put in $cabs. 
There is a way to collect as I need?

Comment: @NirCarmona You are confusing me now.. This question was to search for green cells that contain the word `add` and change these cells. Now you are asking to not change anything in Excel, but only search for green cells and build a second list for cells without color (does white count?) regardless of their value?

Comment: Its very simple. You right I asked how to change the color and I got an answer although the saving is not working if I use  $workbook.Close($true) (use the same name).

As you can see in the fist code I wrote that search all the cells in green and holds the numbers for each green cell $patches = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++)...
If I want to search for all the green cells that has the string 'add' inside and save them at $patches. How can I do that?

Comment: Theo I will be happy to know if it is not impossible to do what I want 
And if it possible it will be great to know how

Comment: @NirCarmona Not difficult at all I would say, **BUT** What do you want to save from these cells. We know they are green and have the word `add` in them, but what is it you want to store in $patches? The cell's row and column number? The value `add` or the patch number from the cell to the left (`$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2`) ??

Comment: Yes. column number 1 holds the number of the patches. 
I want to search for all the cells in column 4 for color and string and hold them in @patches. This is working now only for color or for string. This is why I have $patches and $cabs. And it also limits me to doing more things

Comment: @NirCarmona Please see my update